# Missing Ads Question in Google Play Developer Console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Hi fellow Android Developers, I am trying to complete my google play app publishing, but I can't seem to get pass this Ads sections. There is no question whatsoever.

Does anyone of you encountered this?

[image: y]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED: Disable Adblock in the browser then refresh page.**